# How to determine, and pull the correct Data from a structures with Arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, viewcontroller

I have two table views that get populated from data that are pulled from Arrays according to the cell chosen.I have introduced structures, initially just with arrays of Strings and I am trying to pull the right data and populate the right fields with them.So I have this Struct:

```
  struct DetailView {
    var detailTitle : String
    
    //var equipmentImage = [UIImageView?]()
    var serN : String
    var dc : String //deck Code
    var an : String  //area name
    var sn : String   //Space number
    var manuf : String
    var qty : String
    
    init(detailTitle:String,dc:String,serN:String,an:String,sn:String,manuf:String,qty:String){
        self.detailTitle = detailTitle
        self.dc = dc
        self.an = an
        self.serN = serN
        self.sn = sn
        self.manuf = manuf
        self.qty = qty
//
    }
}
```

I have this array:

```
    //we are adding elements on the detailView structure

    var thirdArray : [DetailView]= []
```

I populate it:

```
    thirdArray = thirdArray = [[
                    DetailView(detailTitle: "A", dc: "", serN: "Info required", an: "Area Name required", sn: "Space Number Required", manuf: "APC", qty: "2")],
                    
                    [DetailView(detailTitle: "B", dc: "", serN: "Info required", an: "Area Name required", sn: "Space Number Required", manuf: "Apple", qty: "12"),
                    DetailView(detailTitle: "D", dc: "", serN: "Info required", an: "Area Name required", sn: "Space Number Required", manuf: "Apple", qty: "7"),
                    DetailView(detailTitle: "E", dc: "", serN: "Info required", an: "Area Name required", sn: "Space Number Required", manuf: "Apple", qty: "1")],
                    
                    
                    [DetailView(detailTitle: "F", dc: "", serN: "Info required", an: "Area Name required", sn: "Space Number Required", manuf: "Autonomic", qty: "1")]]
```

Then I perform a segue where I populate them:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
            let row = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row ?? 0
            let destViewController = segue.destination as! SecondTableViewController
           var detailArray : [DetailView]
           detailArray = thirdArray
destViewController.detailVcArray = detailArray


}
```

on my second table view I have:

```
    var detailVcArray : [DetailView] = []


     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
             let destViewController = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
             let row = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row ?? 0
           


    var lastArray : [DetailView]
    lastArray = detailVcArray
    
    
    destViewController.displayDetail = lastArray[row]
         //here I get this error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"   
        }
```

Lastly on my DetailsViewController I want to populate the dc textField with the dc data from my struct and the textView with the detailTitle etc ..But the app crashes.

```
      var displayDetail : DetailView?
        @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
        @IBOutlet weak var serN: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var dc: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var an: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var sn: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var manuf: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var qty: UITextField!
        
            
         override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
    
    textView.text = displayDetail?.detailTitle
        dc.text = displayDetail?.dc
        serN.text = displayDetail?.serN
        an.text = displayDetail?.an
        sn.text = displayDetail?.sn
        manuf.text = displayDetail?.manuf
        qty.text = displayDetail?.qty
         updateTextView()
                }
```

I get this error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" and the app crashes when I choose a cell from my last TV and trying to present the data on my last VC.

Comment: I don’t get it. You are saying `destViewController.firstString = detailVcArray[row]; destViewController.secondSting = detailVcArray[row]`. So of course they are the same. What’s the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest redesigning your data model around the thing you need to display.  In the end, you want 2 strings, so create that structure.

```
struct Detail {
    var detailTitle: String
    var dc: String
}
```

You want to organize them as an array of arrays to match your two tables.

```
let detailArray = [[Detail(detailTitle: "A", dc: "BO")],
    [Detail(detailTitle: "B", dc: "Apple"), Detail(detailTitle: "C", dc: "Apple"), Detail(detailTitle: "D", dc: "Apple")],
    [Detail(detailTitle: "A", dc: "BD")]
    //  ...
]
```

Your segue picks the correct array and passes it to the second table's data source, which is...

```
var detailVcArray: [Detail]
```

And the last controller receives what it needs as...

```
var displayDetail: Detail
```

At that point you can use the values.

```
    textView.text = displayDetail.detailTitle
    dc.text = displayDetail.dc
```

Comment: -Hi Phillip, the detailTitle and the dc needs to be an array of strings.My intensions are that I have an initial tableView where when clicked on a cell, that cell provides me with a different number of entries picked from a struct containing arrays and lastly when selecting a cell on the second TableView for my data to get presented on the DetailsViewController.

Comment: I believe I understand what you're doing.  But, if you try it, I think you'll find that it's easier to deal with arrays where each item contains matching data rather than managing each data element within its own array.  Why do you say "detailTitle and the dc needs to be an array of strings"?  ...nothing in your question's code uses them as arrays except to pass around...and that's actually why it's not working the way you want.

Comment: -Thank you a lot for trying to help, my first Struct is manufacturers and when you select them from the TV you get the products that they offer(hardware, different number of products per manuf)from a different struct, lastly when we select the product we  present with various information about the specific product that comes from a different struct.I might be doing it completely wrong but so far the first and the second TV seem to pull the right data but not all of them ,meaning that I can just pull one element from the struct to present and not 2 or more for specified outlets.

Comment: My last comment: Yes, and you only get one because you have your data stored in individual arrays.  This code `destViewController.detailVcArray = thirdVCArray.detailTitle` prevents you from having the `dc` portion of your data available in the details view.  If you're not interested in rearranging your data to match your controller structure, there's not much I can do to help.

Comment: -Hi Phillip, of course I am interested on changing my data if this is going to save me from headaches but when I try to change them I get this message "Expected expression" that doesn't let me compile, can I also ask if I will have to make an Array for each entry and lastly is it possible to add a pdf entry in my structure and maybe a URL entry?

Comment: If you show the code that gives the error message, I might be able to help.  My principle is to design the data structure, starting at the end.  The basic data type should be a struct/object containing whatever `DetailsViewController` needs.  Then back up to the controller before that.  It needs at least an array of the structs that `DetailsViewController` uses.  If it needs more than that, maybe it also needs a struct to contain the array.  Finally, the first controller needs an array of whatever the second controller uses.

Comment: - Hi Phillip , I made all the changes that you suggested and thank you for the advice on the structures , I will proceed from now on using your theory!I am getting all different kind of errors now, so when I comment the errors I can segue to the last VC but all fields are empty .I know it has to do with how to determine and send them to the last VC but although I am experimenting all day , I don't seem to be able to pull anything..I also changed the names since yours were more descriptive than mine, thank you for that also.

Comment: Maybe start a new question with the revised code if a solution doesn't become clear.

Comment: -Hi Phillip , sorry if I made you loose your patience, I realised that my array of arrays wasn't there and I made the changes that you suggested.Now everything crushes when I try to determine what goes to my last VC at the line "destViewController.displayDetail = lastArray[row]", can you please bare with my incompetence for a last time and have a look in case it is obvious to you?

Comment: No, the problem is that I didn't realize you'd replaced the code in **this** question with new information.  One thing is you really don't need the local variables `detailArray` and `lastArray`.  Even so, your first segue should be passing `detailArray[row]` rather than the whole array.  What are the values of `row` and of `lastArray` when you crash?

Comment: -Hey Phillip, when I change it to "destViewController.detailVcArray = detailArray[row]" it doesn't compile and gives me this error "Cannot assign value of type 'DetailView' to type '[DetailView]'" on that line.I deleted the detailArray and lastArray.When I comment out the detailArray[row] , it doesn't crass and it performs the segue to the last VC but my fields are empty.

Comment: There's something odd there.  You shouldn't be able to use `detailArray = thirdArray` because one is an array of `DetailView` and the other is an array of arrays.  Anyway, let me know what row and lastArray are at crash time.  What I meant by not needing the local variables is that `destViewController.detailVcArray = thirdArray[row]` and `destViewController.displayDetail = detailVcArray[row]` should be valid.

Comment: - this doesn't let me compile "destViewController.detailVcArray = thirdArray[row]" and the error is "Cannot assign value of type 'DetailView' to type '[DetailView]'" and when I comment it out then it crashes when choosing the cell from second TV at "destViewController.displayDetail = detailVcArray[row]" with this error "hread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" and when this is commented I segue to the last VC but everything is empty. I don't know if this is the answer on "what row and lastArray are at crash time" but I can't access the data of the thirdArray for sure.

Comment: Is the code in your question correct where you set the values of `thirdArray`?  ...right after you say "I populate it:"?  To me, that looks as if you're creating an array of arrays...even though it's not how you declare it.

Comment: @georgebolarakis  Instead of the current confusion, I put together a quick sample of passing nested data.  Please take a look at https://github.com/PhilKMills/ForGeorgeB

Comment: -Good Morning Phillip, I can't thank you enough, you taught me how to pass nested data ,when before I was just using code without properly understanding it!You are amazing, people like you give hope and make all of us try to become better!!Thank you Sensei!!